# Create my custom Xml response in wcf rest service

Tags: xml, rest, wcf, c#-4.0

I want to change the xml response format in wcf rest service
For example

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }
    public List<Item> items {get; set; }  
}

public class Item
{
   public string Key { get; set; } 
   public string Vaule { get; set; }
}
```

The class must be shown in this way

```
<Person Name="Jhon" LastName="Doe">
       <Item Key="Color" Value="White"/>
</Person>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: This is the xml I get

Comment: The above class, are the Data Contracts in my wcf rest service, by default the Xml response format is like this
<Person>
           <Name>Jhon</Name>
            <LastName>Doe</LastName>
           <Items>
                     <Item>
                             <Key>Color</Key>
                             <Value>White</Color>
                     </Item>
           </Items>
</Person>

I want to change this response format by the xml format written above.

Comment: Please edit your question and format the data, so that everything is in one place and it's easy to read.

Comment: You still did not show your code to change the XML output yet... You'd have better chances for help if you show some effort on your own instead of asking people to do your job for you.